# building Debian package with non-standard options

Tags: debian, compiling, package-management, dpkg, configure

I would like to build Debian package from source, using `dpkg-buildpackage`. I have downloaded package source:

```
apt-get -t wheezy-backports source gnucash
```

Inside the file `gnucash-2.6.9/configure` I see, that there are options which can be selected/deselected when building the package.

Debian maintainer has already made the decision for me. But if I want disable some options, how should I do it?

Lets say, I want to compile the package without `--enable-aqbanking`. This option appears in several configuration files:

```
$ grep -rl enable-aqbanking gnucash-2.6.9/
gnucash-2.6.9/packaging/gnucash.spec
gnucash-2.6.9/packaging/gnucash.spec.in
gnucash-2.6.9/configure.ac
gnucash-2.6.9/configure
```

**Which of those should I edit?**

**What is the proper way to do it?**

Comment: I recommend using `debuild` instead. From the `devscripts` package.

Comment: @Faheem Mitha - could you please explain why `debuild` is better ? I am following official howto, which is using `dpkg-buildpackage`

Comment: Why is debuild better? Mostly for relatively minor reasons. It automatically creates a log for you. It handles fakeroot automatically for you. It's customizable. See 'man debuild`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OK, take a look at `gnucash-2.6.x/debian/rules`.

Find the line that says `override_dh_auto_configure:` (line 23 in my case), and add your overrides below it.

In your case `--enable-aqbanking` is already there (for wheezy-backports at least), so simply delete it.

More info can be found in the [man page](http://manpages.debian.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=dh_auto_configure&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=Debian%207.8%20wheezy&format=html&locale=en).

**Update:** In addition, sometimes there's a variable in the `rules` file responsible for passing custom stuff to `configure`. It's usually at the top of the file and is called `DEB_CONFIGURE_EXTRA_FLAGS`.

Comment: thanks, that worked almost perfectly. I only had to remove `aqbanking` from line `13` aswell:  `dh $@ --parallel --with python2,autoreconf,aqbanking`. After that, it compiles without errors.

Comment: Glad it worked, Martin.

Comment: actually, is the above solution universal, or only specific to removing `--enable-aqbanking` ? The thing is, when I try to compile without `--enable-dbi` (line 30), it still requires `libdbi-dev` and the resulting binary is linked with `libdbi1`. So apparently, `dbi` is specified somewhere else as well

Comment: I think `--disable-dbi` should make configure happy.

Comment: @MartinVegter regarding universality: yes, it's pretty universal. I also added notes about `DEB_CONFIGURE_EXTRA_FLAGS` to my answer. But typically it's the `override_dh_auto_configure:` you need.

Comment: Glad it worked. Great question, too, upvoted it.

Answer (score 6):

`gnucash-2.6.9/packaging/gnucash.spec` and `gnucash-2.6.9/packaging/gnucash.spec.in` are not part of the Debian packaging. They are the project's own spec files (the second one is a template) for packaging gnucash in RPM form.

`gnucash-2.6.9/configure.ac` is also part of upstream. This is an Autoconf file which is used to generate the `gnucash-2.6.9/configure`. This `autoconf.ac` file is used by the Debian packaging, but is not part of it.

All the Debian packaging lives inside the `debian/` subdirectory.

The actual build script (which is really just a Makefile), is `debian/rules`, so that is all you need to concern yourself about here. Most Debian packages use the [`debhelper`](https://joeyh.name/code/debhelper/) program. This package happens to use the more recent and modern `dh` variant, which is part of `debhelper`.

Briefly, the way "traditional" `debhelper` works is to offer a suite of standard commands that can be used to build the package, rather than having to do everything from scratch. `dh` is a newer variant which has defaults for every stahdard `debhelper` step, which can be overridden if necessary. Which links up to what A.P. is saying. In this case, the rules file is overriding the default configure step. Hence. you need to modify this `override_dh_auto_configure` target to change what the configure step does. Here is the `override_dh_auto_configure` target:

```
override_dh_auto_configure:
        dh_auto_configure -- \
                --libdir=/usr/lib/$(DEB_HOST_MULTIARCH)/gnucash \
                --infodir=/noinst \
                --mandir=/noinst \
                --docdir=/noinst \
                --disable-static \
                --enable-dbi \
                --enable-ofx \
                --enable-aqbanking \
                --enable-locale-specific-tax \
                --enable-python
```

So, this is overriding the `dh_auto_configure` `debhelper` target. Check out `man dh_auto_configure` for more information about that target.

In this case, the default `dh_auto_configure` would just run `configure` with no arguments, i.e. `./configure`. The override just runs `configure` with the given arguments/option. So, you need to remove the `--enable-aqbanking` argument/option here.

Here are some slides about dh: [Not Your Grandpa's Debhelper](https://joeyh.name/talks/debhelper/debhelper-slides.pdf). There is other information on the net.